# Is there a variable set that can be accessed in gradle/maven for the snapshot uniqueVersion?

Tags: maven, gradle

I haven't seen a viable solution to this and any reference to it is several years old.

When publishing a snapshot version a uniqueVersion is produced by the publish job in gradle/maven ex: 55.0.0-SNAPSHOT/55.0.0-20210701.223725-1.

My question: is there a way to access this value 55.0.0-20210701.223725-1 so I can use it for github tagging with jenkins for when a publish job is run?

Comment: `55.0.0-20210701.223725-1` is technical a SNAPSHOT version. and to be accurate that version is produced by the repository manager and not by jenkins via publish. Furthermore change your version to 55.0.0 and you have a release version ...

Comment: I think the OP knows that it is a SNAPSHOT and the question is whether you can find out during the build (without parsing the log output) which number was generated.